# How to get all parent process names of a set of child processes (in macOS) from the shell?

Tags: bash, macos, zsh

I need to extract and list all of the parent processes by name of a subprocess that has a certain name in macOS.  I suspect this will work just fine in Linux or any other *nix as long as we standardize on GNU tools, which we could use via `MacPorts` or `Homebrew`.

In this case we'll say there's a child process with many different instances named "child name". There are many of these "child name" processes (all with the same name) and various sets of them have different parent processes and subsequently parent process names.

So in an example case of 3 parent processes we would have:

```
kernel_task
└── launchd
    ├── Parent A
    │   ├── Child Name
    │   ├── Child Name
    │   ├── Child Name
    │   ├── Child Name
    │   ├── Child Name
    │   ├── Child Name
    │   └── Child Name
    ├── Parent B
    │   ├── Child Name
    │   ├── Child Name
    │   ├── Child Name
    │   ├── Child Name
    │   ├── Child Name
    │   ├── Child Name
    │   └── Child Name
    └── Parent C
        ├── Child Name
        ├── Child Name
        ├── Child Name
        ├── Child Name
        ├── Child Name
        ├── Child Name
        └── Child Name
```

I want to then be able to execute a script like so:

`$ get_parent_names_of_child "Child Name"` that would then print:

```
Parent A
Parent B
Parent C
```

(I might then pass this to `killall` via xargs or whatever.)

How can this be done?

Comment: Possible Duplicate [How to get parent PID of a given process in GNU/Linux from command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/150117/how-to-get-parent-pid-of-a-given-process-in-gnu-linux-from-command-line/150131)

Comment: The children probably belong to the same process group. Did you consider `killall -g`?

Comment: @xhienne do you know how to find the `pgid` on macOS for processes? `-g` doesn't exist for `killall` there. Also, these processes are all spawned entirely separately in completely isolated instances so I doubt they would have the same `pgid`...

Comment: @ylluminate With killall, no need to have its PGID: you feed it with process names, so the name of one child is enough. I don't know the MacOS version of killall.

Comment: So no @xhienne, this will not work. I did try it, but it doesn't kill the parent processes at all and just causes the apps to go insane.  The parents themselves must be killed and what has been started in the answer below seems to be the right approach, but requires some debugging.

Answer (score 2):

To get the parent PIDs of a process with name "ChildProcess", you can use the script below (with some modifications). To get the complete list of PPIDs, you could just pipe the output of the script into the script as input while output is valid or PID != 0?

```
#!/bin/bash

# usage: ./scriptName "ChildProcessName"

pidName=$1

childProcessIDs=($(pidof ${pidName}))

declare -a parentProcessIDs=()

for(( i=0; i<=${#childProcessIDs[@]}; i++ ))
do
    anotherParent=$(ps -p ${pid:-$$} -o ppid=)
    if [ ! -z "$anotherParent" ]
    then
        parentProcessIDs+=($(printf "%s" ${anotherParent}))
    fi
done

ppids=($(echo "${parentProcessIDs[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u))

# Show results
for(( i=0; i<=${#ppids[@]}; i++ ))
do
    if [ ! -z "${ppids[i]}" ]
    then
        echo "${ppids[i]}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Great start. So on macOS `pidof` is missing therefore there are 2 options: 1) add something like `pidof () { ps -Ac | egrep $@ | awk '{print $1}'; }` near the beginning or 2) `sudo port install pidof`. After this I found that it only returns one pid which is the pid of `zsh` itself that I'm running from... There are running 533 "Child Names" at the moment with 7 actual parents of those "Child Names". I can also run `get_parent_names_of_child.sh ANYTHING` and it will always return the pid of the current `zsh` instance...